# java component not visible in windows 8 and 10 or its variant due to corrupted graphics driver

Tags: java, javafx, windows-10

I tested my application based on java(javafx)  in various version of windows(7,8,10) and it worked perfectly but when i tried to run it my client machine(Windows-10 Home(freshly installed)), it is getting run but the internal component of it is not visible, only thing what i can see is border, minimize,maximize and close button. [image]

For the sake of convenience, attached here 
are the results of simple java program or output which I got in my machine and client's machine respectively:

However when i made the same version of jar using Swing...it worked.

Note: Required version of JRE is there in system.

Follwing is the source code:::
the code is simple:::

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package hello;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author oa
 */
public class Hello extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Note: I can smell the conflicts between javafx and windows-10 version

Comment: can you give me the reason why this question is unuseful???

Comment: Kindly let me know, if further elaboration is needed.

Comment: We need **runnable** source code so we can diagnose the problem.

Comment: the code is simple:::

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see your simple, runnable source code as part of your question.

Comment: if youll scroll down, yoll get the same Gilbert

Comment: There is no issue in source code Gilbert

Comment: The thing is component of javafx is not visible in my client's machine(Windows 10 Home). However in another window 10 machine its working

Comment: Which (exact) java version is being used to run it on each machine?

Comment: its same ...the latest version of java

Comment: to be specific.... java hotspot server vm 1.8.0_101

Comment: james i think its conflict between javafx and windows 10 version

Comment: can you help me in sorting this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got a solution, after an hour of work out... As javafx rely on the graphic card installed on the system..
For JavaFX applications to take advantage of the new hardware acceleration pipeline provided by JavaFX, your system must feature one of a wide range of GPUs currently available in the market. If your system does not support hardware acceleration, then JavaFX uses the Java2D software pipeline.
 so one has to ensure that its working properly. In any case if its corrupted or not working properly then javafx doesnt give you the desired result. So in any case if you found that your graphics card is not working properly then just disable it(graphics card)... the javafx will give the desired result thereafter. So basically it was not an WINDOWS 10 and javafx problem...it was graphic related issues